# Error while trying to compile my ModCoderPack mod for Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to make a mod for Minecraft using Mod Coder Pack, however when I try to recompile I get the error that I cannot use lambda expressions but I have set Java 1.8 in Eclipse and I am not sure how to tell it to recompile using -source 8.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

src\minecraft\me\rhysespuff\aeriolus\modules\ModuleManager.java:46: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6
                return modules.stream().filter(module -> module.getName().equals(name)).findFirst().orElse(null);
                                                      ^

(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

Comment: Consider https://github.com/Hexeption/MCP-Reborn

Answer (score 1):

MCP is no longer updated and uses a java version before java 8, which is why lambdas won't work. I would suggest switching to [Minecraft Forge](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/) or [Spigot](http://ww8.spigot.net/), which are modern api's that are still supported and work with java 8.

Comment: I am not sure why it works fine in eclipse but will not recompile.

Comment: Most likely, eclipse is set up to use a different java version than eclipse, so eclipse doesn't show any errors, but it can't compile because MCP is not written for java 8.